# Local home exectution restarts Google Nest hub

Tags: local, execution, google-smart-home

When trying a HTTP local execution to an device from a Google Nest hub, the hub restarts. Fullfillment, Discovery and identify are OK. The code used :

```
      const deviceCommand = new smarthome.DataFlow.HttpRequestData();
      deviceCommand.data =  "";
      deviceCommand.deviceId = device.id;
      deviceCommand.isSecure = false;
      deviceCommand.method = smarthome.Constants.HttpOperation.GET;
      deviceCommand.port = 80;
      deviceCommand.protocol = smarthome.Constants.Protocol.HTTP;
      deviceCommand.requestId = executeRequest.requestId;
      deviceCommand.path = "http://192.168.1.10/json.htm?command=On";
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the entire target URL in the `path` argument, just the path portion. The `DeviceManager` API knows the target address of the device based on the `deviceId` and will construct the proper URL.

I would expect your command should look more like this (note I also removed a few extra properties you shouldn't need to include):

```
const deviceCommand = new smarthome.DataFlow.HttpRequestData();
deviceCommand.deviceId = device.id;
deviceCommand.isSecure = false;
deviceCommand.method = smarthome.Constants.HttpOperation.GET;
deviceCommand.port = 80;
deviceCommand.requestId = executeRequest.requestId;
deviceCommand.path = "/json.htm?Command=On";
```

Comment: Tnx Devunwired, that was the first thing i've tried knowing that the IP should come from the discovery. I changed the path with a leading slash and it works. So many thanks. So the path is now : ```deviceCommand.path = "/json.htm?Command=On"```

Comment: Awesome, edited the answer so future readers will see the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using `deviceCommand.path = "/json.htm?Command=On"`